# Different textarea control against different buttons in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Recently I am making a webpage in Visual Studio 2012 using asp.net for my school project. Now  I want to open two different textarea against of to different button click event. I mean, suppose there are two buttons; 'Add' & 'View' and two textarea. When the page is loaded, Textarea1 will show and Textarea2 will be hidden. When I click on View button, it will show Textarea2 and hide Textarea1 **without reload the page**. As well as when I click on Add button, it will show Textarea1 and hide Textarea2 **without reload the page**.
How can I do this?
Please help!!
Thanks in advance..

Comment: do you have a snippet code...

Comment: No, I have no snippet code!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope this will help you!!!!

```
  <asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50"Rows="5"runat="server" />
  <asp:TextBox id="TextArea2" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="DodgerBlue"Height="45" Width="150"/>
  <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="view" OnClick="Button2_Click" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="DodgerBlue"Height="45" Width="150"/> 

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    TextArea1 .Visible = true;
    TextArea2 .Visible = false;
  }

  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    TextArea1 .Visible = false;
    TextArea2 .Visible = true;
  }
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    TextArea1 .Visible = true;
    TextArea2 .Visible = false;
  }
```